# too many symbolic links encountered, open '/Users//node_modules/lodash/npm-shrinkwrap.json'

Tags: npm, npm-install

After running the following command 
npm i lodash
I was unable to perform npm install or any other command.

I tried npm uninstall lodash but it gave me the same error.

```
hectorjimenez$ npm uninstall lodash
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/hectorjimenez/node_modules/lodash/npm-shrinkwrap.json
npm ERR! errno -62
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open '/Users/hectorjimenez/node_modules/lodash/npm-shrinkwrap.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hectorjimenez/.npm/_logs/2019-09-26T22_59_31_518Z-debug.log
```

I am really lost in here, hope you can help, thanks!

Comment: node_modules/core.js folder must be corrupted

Comment: and what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `/node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again in your project's root directory.